# Storing variables across pages with no sessions PHP

Tags: php, temp

I am working on some code that is for machine to machine communication with XML . The devices connecting will not support sessions. I need PHP variables that work across pages with no session support.

I have used in a few places

```
file_put_contents($file,$content)
```

This works but this is going to make a lot of disk reads and writes when I am done

Furthermore reading the php manual for php://fd and php://temp I can not get this to work. 
https://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

I have tried this many ways and do not understand how it works . Also some of these methods are volitile meaning once they are read they are gone . I know once I read it as a variable I can re-write it back to php://temp or php://fd for later use on another page.

Maybe there is a better way to do what I need?

I am approching 10 disk accesses per page and it is certain to slow it all down. Each disk access has a single string about the length of a word, so writing and reading to/from disk seems crazy

Comment: What do you mean by "The devices connecting will not support sessions"? Sessions are a server/php feature, not a client feature. Please [edit] your question to include a detailed description of what you want to do.

Comment: i tested with php sessions over and over. I had each page write out session variables abd they did not hold. As I recall sessions depend on cookies if a cookie is not stored then the session is lost. I no longer desire to diagnose the sessions issye these are not web browsers and they behave differently.

Answer (score 0):

The problem would seem to be that the user-agents in question are not supporting *cookies* (they are not web browsers, as you say), not that they don't support "sessions". *Sessions* are, after all, mantained server-side.

> ... sessions depend on cookies if a cookie is not stored then the session is lost.

Sessions don't need to use cookies. With regards to sessions, the cookie is "simply" used to propagate the "session id". Using cookies is the default, preferred and most secure method of doing this, but it is not the only way.

The "session id" (stored as part of the `SID` constant) can instead be passed as a URL parameter or as POST data.

The config settings `session.use_cookies` and `session.use_only_cookies` can be disabled (ie. set to "0") so that PHP will not even try to set a session cookie. You can then enable `session.use_trans_sid` (ie. set to "1") for PHP to automcatically rewrite the URLs to contain the necessary "session id" or manually use the `SID` constant to construct your URLs.

When PHP recieves the session id, in either a cookie, URL parameter or POST data it will resume the session when `session_start()` is called. No cookie required.

Reference:

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.constants.php

---

> I am approching 10 disk accesses per page and it is certain to slow it all down.

10 disk accesses per page request is not really that much and is unlikely to impact performance. The default PHP session handler uses "files", so this also incurs disk accesses, although probably just 1 per user session I would think, if the data is small.